# QGIS strongly offsetted symbols for categorized layers not visible on layer list (layer panel)?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I am constructing a symbology for telecom analysis, which so far is mainly point and line features.

So far it is working very well except that I have to offset the symbols to be able to avoid superposition and cluttering, and that also is OK except that the offset has to be of such a magnitude that the symbols are not longer visible on the layers panel.

Since there are many symbols, it is very important that the user of the map can see quickly the meaning of the symbols but since the spacing is fixed on this panel all  that is visible in layer panel are the names of the categories and blanks where the symbol should be visible.

Is it possible to modify (increase) the spacing between categories in the layers panel?

I am using QGIS 2.2.